# Travel to/from Germany without a passport

Tags: schengen, passports, germany

I'm not going to have my passport for 3/4 weeks in Germany, but I was hoping to go, probably by bus, to Poland/France at some point. I will have a student card, scan of my passport and a certificate of German residence registration, and I'm not an EU citizen (Australian). What are my prospects? Would like to not get in trouble. Should I check the individual companies' passport control policies?